# Fail to rename a file in Qt with QDir::rename()

Tags: file, qt, text, rename, qdir

I'm using `QDir::rename()` to rename a temporary file.

here's my code:

```
// change the temporary filename
void save::finish()
{
    QString newpath = ui->path->text();

    QString newname = ui->filename->text();

    newpath.append("/");
    newpath.append(newname);
    newpath.append(".txt");

    QDir r;

    bool check = r.rename("temp.txt", newname);

    if (check == true)
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","Saved successfully!", QMessageBox::Ok);
        close();
    }

    else
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this,"Error","Error saving! Please try again.", QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
}
```

the file is renamed but it stays in the same directory as the temporary file. I don't get what's wrong.

Comment: Does your destination folder exist?

Comment: I am sure you already printed out a newpath just to make sure it is a valid path to a new location. It is really strange that rename does not occur. Which OS are you running this on? Just in case, run your newly created "newpath" variable through QDir::toNativeSeparators() (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#toNativeSeparators) before sending it to rename method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try

```
bool check = r.rename("temp.txt", newpath);
```

I see you have a `QString` called `newpath` that is not used in the rename call but you pass `newname` which you've appended to `newpath` just in the previous line. From code you've posted looks like your just giving a new name and hence why the result file is in the same folder as the original but did get renamed.

Do remember that even with giving a full path [QDir::rename](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#rename) will fail if source and destination path's are not on the same partition or for a few more reasons as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I guess that's the problem. Just a lack of attention. My bad.